# Get-ADUser - count users with the same Surname and email (excluding numbers)

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to count user accounts with the same Surname and email. The problem is that strings representing those properties can include numbers.
In AD can exists, for example, accounts like

1. Anne Smith, anne.smith@mail.pl
2. Anne Smith 23, anne.smith23@mail.pl
3. Anne Smithy, anne.smithy@mail.pl.

Numbers are only for making accounts and mail addresses unique.
Search for Anne Smith shall list 1st and 2nd position.

For now I have a piece of code to do this.

```
$Inni = Get-ADUser -Filter "(sn -like '$($UserWzor.Surname)*') -and (GivenName -eq '$($UserWzor.GivenName)')" -Server $DC -Properties sAMAccountName, sn, givenName, displayName, mail | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.sAMAccountName -ne $UserAD.sAMAccountName } | Select-Object -Property sAMAccountName, sn, givenName, displayName, mail
$IluInnych1 = 0
$IluInnych2 = 0
foreach ($Inny in $Inni)        {
    $InnyNazwisko = $Inny.sn -replace '[ ]\d+$'
    $InnyImie = $Inny.GivenName
    if (($InnyNazwisko -eq $UserWzor.Surname) -and ($InnyImie -eq $UserWzor.GivenName)) { $IluInnych1++ }
    $InnyMail = [regex]::replace(($Inny.mail).Split("@")[0], '\d+$', "")
    if ($InnyMail -eq $NowyMail){ $IluInnych2++ }
}
```

I don't need to know those other Anne Smith data but only the number of them so I can rename an account by adding next not ocupied number to it's DisplayName and mail properties.

Since `-Filter` option doesn't allow to use regular expressions I tried to put it  in the `Where-Object` part of the query or even `ForEach-Object` loop between `Get-AdUser` and `Where-Object` but with no success.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "(sn -like '$($UserWzor.Surname)*') -and (GivenName -eq '$($UserWzor.GivenName)')" -Server $DC | ForEach-Object { $_.sn = $_.sn -replace '[ ]*\d+$' } | Where-Object -FilterScript { ($_.sAMAccountName -ne $UserAD.sAMAccountName) -and ($_.sn -eq $UserWzor.Surname) }
```

Result of this query is empty.

Is it possible to do this simpler way than presented?

Comment: Why would a surname have numbers?  Numbers are also significant in an email address.

Comment: I don't know why. I used to remove numbers from surnames for my users but I have to deal with them for users in other AD OUs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below regex:

```
[\w]*? ([\w]*).*?, ([\w\d@.]*)
```

And for those, whose Group1 and Group 2 is same ,are the ones that needs to be shortlisted.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/RiOCf5/1

Test:

```
Anne Smith, anne.smith@mail.pl
Anne Smith 23, anne.smith23@mail.pl
Anne Smithy, anne.smithy@mail.pl
```

Match:

```
Match 1
Group 1.    5-10    `Smith`
Group 2.    12-30   `anne.smith@mail.pl`

Match 2
Group 1.    36-41   `Smith`
Group 2.    46-66   `anne.smith23@mail.pl`

Match 3
Group 1.    72-78   `Smithy`
Group 2.    80-99   `anne.smithy@mail.pl`
```

Results in Powershell:

```
[regex]::Match('Anne Smith, anne.smith@mail.pl','[\w]*? ([\w]*).*?, ([\w\d@.]*)').captures.groups[1].value
[regex]::Match('Anne Smith 23, anne.smith23@mail.pl','[\w]*? ([\w]*).*?, ([\w\d@.]*)').captures.groups[1].value
[regex]::Match('Anne Smithy, anne.smithy@mail.pl','[\w]*? ([\w]*).*?, ([\w\d@.]*)').captures.groups[1].value
```

Output:

```
Smith
Smith
Smithy
```

Comment: I don't know how to include your concept into my task. Finally I made to work Get-ADUser query - `Get-ADUser -Filter "(sn -like '$($UserWzor.Surname)*') -and (GivenName -eq '$($UserWzor.GivenName)')" -Server $DC -Properties sAMAccountName, sn, givenName, displayName, mail, proxyaddresses | Where-Object -FilterScript { ($_.sAMAccountName -ne $SAM) -and (($_.sn -replace '[ ]\d+$') -eq $UserWzor.Surname) } | Select-Object -Property sAMAccountName, sn, givenName, displayName, mail, @{ L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = { $_.ProxyAddresses -join ";" } }`

Comment: Post it as an answer, so that it can help other users as well